# Как использовать отладку при запуске программы?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2017

Первая программа запускает вторую. У второй меняются относительные пути на путь расположения первой. Путь становится неверным.

При этом я не могу использовать режим отладки чтобы посмотреть какой путь неверный, тк эта программа запускается не в visual studio а через другую.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проще всего вот как.

В подходящем месте в начале второй программы напишите

```
if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
    Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

Первую программу запускайте без Visual Studio. Когда вторая программа будет запущена, появится диалог:

[image: приаттачьте дебаггер!]

Выберите в нём экземпляр Visual Studio для отладки и нажмите OK. Откроется отладчик Visual Studio и загрузит вашу программу.

Comment: У вас VS на русском языке специально для таких ответов ? :)

Comment: @Nikita: VS у меня английская, это русская локаль Windows даёт такой текст :)

Comment: Достаточно только одной строчки, две сразу не нужны. Или `Launch`, или `Break`

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Насколько я понимаю, Launch не гарантирует _остановку_ программы, только присоединение отладчика. А на моей машине одиночный break игнорируется, уж не знаю почему (судя по всему, настройки Windows?)

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно именно отладить косвенно запускаемый процесс, а не просто приаттачить отладчик в определенный момент, или если не хочется менять код и пересобирать стороннее приложение ради остановки, то можно использовать расширение [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GreggMiskelly.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool).

Устанавливаете его в студию, включаете отладку в настройках. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставите чекбокс Enable native code debugging в свойствах проекта:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и студия начинает автоаттачить дебаггер к дочерним процессам.